# Kde connect problem

Tags: kubuntu, kde, android, kde-connect

I have latest version of KDE connect installed on Xiaomi mi4i (lollipop). So far it's working great for notifications,multimedia control and remote input. I'm on Plasma 5.8 (Kubuntu 16.04).

But whenever I try to access my mobile folders, it shows error. It does display the name such as internal storage and SD card, but on clicking:

[image: screenshot]

How to fix it?

Comment: Found this thread [Error on KDE Connect][1]
  [1]: http://www.pclinuxos.com/forum/index.php?topic=133878.0

Please check once...

Comment: Please, Can you simplify it and tell, I couldn't exactly follow those steps.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been fixed in a newer version of KDE Connect